# Elementary number theory problem: If $m$ is a prime number and $a,b$ two numbers less than $m$, then prove the following

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**

> If $m$ is a prime number and $a,b$ two **distinct** positive integers less than $m$ then
>   prove that$$a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}b+a^{m-4}b^2+\cdots +b^{m-2}$$is a multiple
>   of $m$

**Source:**

Found it on a mock test paper. I have just started learning number theory (thanks fleablood) for an exam, and I'm learning all of it on my own. The problem looks like a simple one but I can't seem to solve it.

**My try:**

The given expression looks very similar to binomial expansion of $(a+b)^{m-2}$
$$(a+b)^{m-2} = {{m-2}\choose{0}}a^{m-2}+{{m-2}\choose{1}}a^{m-3}b+\cdots+{{m-2}\choose{m-2}}b^{m-2}$$or
$$(a+b)^{m-2} = a^{m-2}+{{m-2}\choose{1}}a^{m-3}b+\cdots+b^{m-2}$$
Now I have read a theorem which states that

*The coefficient of every term in the expansion of $(a+b)^{p}$, except the first and the last, is divisible by $p$ where $p$ is a prime number*

Which means that all the middle terms (except first and last) of the binomial expansion are divisible by $m$. But what about the first and last terms? And also the function given in problem is not a binomial expansion. How do I proceed? All help appreciated!

Comment: $(x^n - y^n) = (x - y)(x^{n - 1) + ... + y^{n - 1}).$ Also try using fermat's little.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to number theory, so any references please @ntntnt ?

Comment: Wait do you want me to explain fermat's little or link you something that explains it?

Comment: It is false for $a=b$. Take $m=5$ and $a=b=2$.

Comment: Or $a=b=1, n=3$

Comment: salvage if possible!!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry @ntntnt I didn't know it by name, but upon looking I do know the theorem. How does it fit into the question?

Comment: The original formulation was "two numbers" which is unlucky. We not only have to rule out $a=b$, $a=0$ or $b=0$ would be fatal as well (Only $a=b=0$ would work, if $0$ is considered to be a multiple of $m$)

Comment: @YourAverageEuler I think you would have seen it if you factored in a different way!

Comment: @RobertZ please read the question now. It says 2 distinct numbers..

Comment: @YourAverageEuler I edited the question because the original formulation was too imprecise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the the condition only holds for $a\neq b$

We have $$a^{m-1}-b^{m-1}=(a-b)(a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}\ b+\ldots+b^{m-2}\ )$$

We also have, by Fermat's Little Theorem, that $$a^{p-1}\ \equiv 1\pmod p,$$ where $p$ is a prime, and $p\nmid a$.

It therefore follows that $$(a-b)(a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}\ b+\ldots+b^{m-2}\ )\ \equiv 0\pmod m$$$$\Rightarrow m\mid (a-b)\;\; OR\;\;m\mid (a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}\ b+\ldots+b^{m-2}\ )$$
The aboce follows from that $m$ is a prime.

Since we have $a,b\lt n$, and $a\neq b$, we conclude $m\nmid (a-b)$
$$\Rightarrow m\mid (a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}\ b+\ldots+b^{m-2}\ )$$

Comment: perfect! I'm not familiar with the mod function (will learn it very soon) and try to understand what you mean. Thanks for the effort and time!

Comment: What about Fermat's theorem?

Comment: If someone do not know about modular arithmetic then asking him about Fermat little theorem doesn't make sense. :-P

Comment: I guess you're right!

Answer (score 3):

If $a\not=b$ then
$$a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}b+a^{m-4}b^2+\cdots +b^{m-2}=\frac{(a^{m-1}-1)-(b^{m-1}-1)}{a-b}.$$ 
which is divisible by the prime $m$ because, by the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $m$  divide $(a^{m-1}-1)$ and $(b^{m-1}-1)$ while $0<|a-b|<m$.

P.S. The property is false for $a=b$ because the prime $m$ does not divide
$$a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}b+a^{m-4}b^2+\cdots +b^{m-2}=(m-1)a^{m-2}.$$

Comment: @YourAverageEuler I edited my answer according to the modified statement.

Answer (score 1):

I let you conclude why it is wrong for $a=b$ from the theory below.

Note that you expression is equivalent to $\frac{a^{m-1}-b^{m-1}}{a-b}$.

Since $a,b$ are smaller than $m$, we only need to prove that $a^{m-1} -b^{m-1}$ is divisible by $m$. Which is true (using Fermat little theorem) since $a,b$ are smaller  than $m$ and hence coprime to it as m is a prime .

Comment: defo it is cuz the denominator will be 0. But I still don't understand...

Comment: No, that's not right@YourAverageEuler. You can only divide $if$ $a\neq b$

Comment: The reason for $a\neq b$ follows simply from that the required result doesn't hold true for $a=b$

Comment: @YourAverageEuler Well a nicer reason is that if $a=b$ then the LHS of you expression equals $(m-1)a^{m-2}$ which is not divisible by $m$.

Comment: You're right; that's how I noticed it:)

Comment: Ok, thanks for correcting me @VidyanshuMishra